# distribute web applications to mobile platforms?

Tags: web-applications

I have been looking for an answer on google but no luck...

can you distribute web applications to mobile platforms? so you can just write and update once. can you create an android or iOS application only to securely point to the web app?

Comment: what do you mean by distribute web applications to mobile platforms?
Search about PWA's Progressive Web Apps.
Progressive - Works for every user, regardless of browser choice because it's built with progressive enhancement.
Responsive - Fits any form factor: desktop, mobile, tablet, or whatever is next.
 I think that's what you are looking for

Comment: You can try `Cordova` + `Ionic`

Comment: so when people go in to the mobile stores they can download the app so it will seem like a native app. then when its opened it uses the web application